# SQL Server : convert column string to discrete integer numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say that I have a column `weather` (of a string type), all it values in fact are limited, for example, we can suppose, it only have five values with `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`, `DDD`, `EEE`.

Since I want to do some machine learning algorithms, I want to change the column type to `INT`, and at the same time, change its values into numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` (corresponding to the existing values `AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE`).

How to write the T-SQL code ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?!? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: @jarlh sorry, I have deleted the unrelated labels.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Do `ALTER TABLE` to add a new column `new_weather_col` integer.

**2.** Do an `UPDATE` to set `new_weather_col`'s values:

```
update tablename
set new_weather_col = case weather when 'AAA' then 1
                                   when 'BBB' then 2
                                   when 'CCC' then 3
                                   when 'DDD' then 4
                                   when 'EEE' then 5
                      end;
```

**3.** `ALTER TABLE` to drop the old weather column.

**4.** `ALTER TABLE` again, this time to rename `new_weather_col` to `weather`.

(Edit: *Perhaps I should add step 0 - make sure you have your table backup-ed before proceeding.*)

Comment: Don't forget to `DROP COLUMN weather` before renaming.

Comment: OK, that solved my problem, thank you very much @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

Create another table with two columns: an int and a string. Populate the new table with your 5 strings and 5 unique integers. Join the two tables together by the string. Viola, you have integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to write an SQL query for this which returns integers instead of string, you can do this in a case statement since you have fixed set of values.

```
select 1, case when weather = 'AAA' then 1 
                 when weather = 'BBB' then 2 
                 when weather = 'CCC' then 3
when weather = 'DDD' then 4
when weather = 'EEE' then 5 

            end 
from DUAL;
```

I have used pl sql here. You can also do this in MySQL. The query snippet is just to give you an example. This will not run on the sql client.